# Deleting a directory from the path to the URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There is a link like

```
domain.com/dir/page
```

It displays the contents of the page **page.php**, which is located in the **dir** directory of the site.

Current view **.htaccess** at the root of the site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

How do I replace the URL with **domain.com/dir/page** to **domain.com/page** (that is, remove **dir** from the path)?

P.S. It is understood that the solution should work for all URLs of the specified type.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your `.htaccess` file, make sure it is above any other rules that you have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your cache **before** you test this.

Comment: Thanks. You answered the question perfectly. Sorry the original asker didn't give props for it.